# Bilinear forms on R^n: What is the exact meaning of the indices i and j for <ei,ej>

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form, change-of-basis

> Let $f:\mathbf{R}^2\to\mathbf{R}^2$, $f\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ y_1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}x_2 \\ y_2\end{bmatrix}\right) = 2x_1x_2 + 3x_1y_2 + x_2y_1$.
> As an example we want to represent $f$ with the **standard basis**. It follows that: $$f(e_1,e_1)=2 \ ;\ f(e_1,e_2)=3 \ ; \ f(e_2,e_1) = 1 \ ; \ f(e_2,e_2)=0 $$

Hey,

Can someone explain to me how e.g. $f(e_1, e_1) = 2$, according to the definition of bilinear forms and matrices? I think i am confused about the indices. I do not really understand what $e_1$ is referring to: is it the first row of the identity-matrix?

I added the example of my class and my question as a picture (i dont know how to write mathematical expression on my computer)

Q:

> - What does $f(e_1,e_1)$ mean?
> - How is it related to the theorem of bilinear forms:
>   $$\boxed{f(v,w) = v\ ^t\!Aw = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}v_iw_j}$$

Comment: $e_1=\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1  \\
   0  \\
\end{array}} \right]$, $e_2=\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   0  \\
   1  \\
\end{array}} \right]$, the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: $e_1$ is the first vector of the standard basis, i.e. $e_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and similarly for $e_2$.

Comment: In general, in $\Bbb R^n$, $e_i$ is the vector with zeroes everywhere except for a $1$ in the $i$'th position.  In $\Bbb R^6$ for instance $e_3 = (0,0,1,0,0,0)$.  Adjust as desired to being column vectors if necessary.  There is little fundamental difference between the $\Bbb R^6$ which consists of column vectors of length $6$ and the $\Bbb R^6$ which consists of row vectors of length $6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will see, $\beta=\{e_1,e_2\}$ is a basis for $R^2$.
So, what you define bilinear form $f$ as $[f]_\beta$ and correspondingly you find the respective coordinates of the matrix that is, for example,
You say $f(e_1,e_1)$ is first element of first row and you calculated that $f(e_1,e_1)=2$. Likewise, you calculate other entries!!
Hope it helps!!